# CRC computation

Tags: number-theory, computer-science, coding-theory

I would like to understand the CRC computation using CCITT CRC-16 $x^{16} + x^{12} +x^{5} +1$. I was able to successfully implement it in a program but I would like to understand the computation behind it. I was not succesful in the paper-n-pen technique. Is the CRC computation with CRC-16 different.

Any useful hints in this direction.

P.S : I am not keen on the program or the shift register implementation but the traditional way of computing CRC with polynomials or binary sequence using binary division technique.

Thanks for reading

Comment: You can't be completely ignorant if you know enough to implement the computation in a program. Please tell us more about what it is you feel is unclear. Just unspecified "useful hints" are difficult to provide when we don't know which state of knowledge they have to be useful _in_.

Comment: Well, implementation was pretty  easy I would say. There was an algoirthm on the compututation of CRC in the technical spec of 802.11b But I tried to compute by actually dividing the Message polynomial by the Gen.Polynomial $x^16+x^12+x^5+1$ but the reminder was not what I had expected.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A CRC computation is as follows.  You have a data polynomial 
$d(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} d_ix^i$ where the $d_i \in \{0, 1\}$ are 
$n$ bits to
be transmitted (or recorded).  What is actually transmitted (or 
recorded) is 
$$t(x) = x^{16}d(x) + p(x)$$
where $p(x)$ is the ${\textit remainder~polynomial}$ 
when $x^{16}d(x)$ is divided by the CRC polynomial 
$C(x) = x^{16} + x^{12} + x^5 + 1$.  Note that polynomial division yields
$$
x^{16}d(x) = q(x)C(x) + p(x)
$$
where the quotient $q(x)$ is discarded.  But the above equation 
can be re-arranged as
$$
q(x)C(x) = x^{16}d(x) - p(x) = x^{16}d(x) + p(x) = t(x)
$$ 
(because arithmetic on the polynomial coefficients is done modulo $2$
and subtraction is thus the same as addition),
and thus $t(x)$ is a multiple of the CRC polynomial $C(x)$.
Since $p(x)$ is of degree $15$ or less, the
high-order coefficients of the polynomial $t(x)$ are the data bits
while the low-order coefficients are the so-called CRC bits or parity
bits, that is
$$
t(x) = d_{n-1}x^{n-1 + 16} + d_{n-2}x^{n-2+16}
+ \cdots d_0x^{16} + p_{15}x^{15} + p_{14}x^{14} + \cdots + p_0.
$$

In computing $p(x)$ via polynomial long division using paper and pencil,
you need to remember that

(i) $\quad \quad$ $d(x)$ is multiplied by $x^{16}$ before
beginning the long division

(ii) $\quad \quad$ the subtractions of polynomial coefficients that occur in
the long division process are all done modulo $2$ and thus are the same as additions modulo $2$ (that is, the XOR operation)

(iii) $\quad \quad$ the long division continues till $x^{16}d_0$ is processed
and the remainder is a polynomial of degree $15$ or less.

Practical CRC systems often have bells-and-whistles (such as the high-order
bits $8$ bits in $x^{16}d(x)$ are complemented before the division process
begins etc.) which I have not included above because these are likely
not  of interest in this forum.  However, ignoring such details in your 
paper-and-pencil computations will make your results differ
from the ones your machine is giving you.

At the receiving (or reading) end, what you have is a polynomial
$r(x)$ which might be $\textit slightly$ different from $t(x)$
if transmission (or read) errors changed some of the bits.  The
CRC error detection process merely divides $r(x)$ by $C(x)$; no
need to multiply $r(x)$ by $x^{16}$ first.   If
the remainder is nonzero, then $r(x)$ is $\textit not$ a multiple
of $C(x)$ and so the receiver knows that transmission (or read) errors
have occurred.  But if the remainder is $0$, then $r(x)$ is a 
multiple of $C(x)$, and
with high probability, is the same as $t(x)$.  The low-order
$16$ bits in $r(x)$ are discarded and the high-order $n$ bits
are accepted as error-free data. When the remainder is $0$, there 
is a small probability that the difference between $r(x)$ and $t(x)$ 
is a multiple of $C(x)$.  Such errors are referred to as undetected
errors.  The probability of undetected error decreases as the degree
of $C(x)$ increases.  For this reason, many modern systems use 
CRC polynomials of degree 32.

Comment: Thanks Dilip, I think I missed multiplying $x^{16}$ to d(n). Thanks taking time in explaining to me.

Comment: I missed it again, I tried multiplying d(x) is multiplied by $x^{16}$ before beginning the long division, but p(x) was not what I had expected.
In the shift register implementation, I initially set the contents to all 1's, will dividing the  $x^{16}$ *d(x)/t(x), do we need to handle this ? How does this change the calculations. 

I am trying to understand the CRC computation in IEEE 802.11 Standard

Thanks

Comment: I don't have access to the IEEE 802.11 standard and so don't know how it does things.  But initial loading with all $1$s is one of the bells or whistles I mentioned as likely to be uninteresting to readers of this forum.

Comment: thanks a lot, would it be possible to direct me to a reference where they talk of this exception and how the polynomial changes, how it changes in the computation of  CRC ?

Comment: http://www.ross.net/crc/crcpaper.html

Comment: I read multiple articles about CRCs before finding this Q/A.  This makes it clear in such little writing what a CRC calculation is doing.  It makes me wonder if the authors of online resources know what they're saying or are just parroting "facts".  TY for this answer.