# How to compute the Galois Field (multiply, GF(2^n))?

Tags: finite-fields

I'm a rookie for finite fields.
I know that the solution of computing multiplication in GF(2^n), needs to use the degree n irreducible polynomial over GF(2). But I have no idea of the details.
Here is an example,
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqlgf.png)

$(x-1)^{-1} g(x)$ in $GF(2^n)$ for $g(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (b_i x^i)$ where the degree n irreducible polynomial over $GF(2)$ is $p(x) = x^n + \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (c_i x^i)$

I also understand that the GF(2) multiplication is equalized to the logical AND operation. Could someone explain more details of this example?

Comment: The latter half of [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/76136/11619) may help. Or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/89805/11619).

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/591254/11619) I once prepared for referrals (mostly for slightly different stuff) has a few more examples.

Comment: And for examples and explanations about finding the inverse I refer you to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/124300/11619). Other examples are linked to that one. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/505619/11619) is a characteristic two example of the same process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I’ll check and try it.

Comment: I still have no idea to solve my problem.